# IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am looking to setup an Eclipse development environment with IBM Worklight v5.0.5 Fix pack 1.
Can I get some pointers on the installation links for older versions of Worklight?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, as it is asking to locate a piece of software.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See available downloads below.
Note that these links do not guarantee each download to be the latest patched version of each release. Latest patches are available only from the IBM Fix Central website.

- IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.0 (available from the Eclipse Marketplace). Note that v8.0 is very different from previous releases. [Learn more](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/ibm-releases-next-generation-of-mobilefirst-foundation-built-for-hybrid-cloud/).
- IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1.0.0 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_7.1.0.zip))
- IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0.0.0 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_7.0.0.zip))
- IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3.0.0 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_6.3.0.0.zip))
- IBM Worklight Foundation 6.2.0.1 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/iws_eclipse_6.2.0.1.zip))
- IBM Worklight 6.1.0.2 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/iws_update_site_wde.6.1.0.2.zip))
- IBM Worklight 6.0.0.2 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.2.zip))
- IBM Worklight 5.0.6.2 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/iws_update_site_wde.5.0.6.2.zip))

Comment: the direct link is now a 404

Comment: I've updated the current version to 6.1 and link for previous version to 6.0.0.2.

Comment: I have downloaded one of the zip files from the links above.  But how do I install it into Eclipse?

Comment: Help > Install new software... > Add > Archive

Comment: @IdanAdar The links don't seem to work now. Can you please update the links?

Comment: Appears to be an FTP problem. Nothing I can do about that. Check again later

Comment: Yes it is. Worked fine after some time. Thanks :)

Comment: @IdanAdar can you please have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716321/ibm-mobilefirst-custom-direct-update-is-not-happening-in-ionic2?noredirect

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Idan's response, if you have purchased a Worklight license, you can then download install files for older versions from IBM's Passport Advantage site. Once a new version is pushed to the the Eclipse Marketplace, this is the only way to get an older version of Studio.

I recommend to our team that they install new copies of Eclipse for each new version of Worklight Studio, so that they can support any applications that have not been updated yet.

Comment: There is a new version of WL studio in the marketplace almost every week, so I imagine you only install a new copy on major releases? We face the problem that if one member of the team updates to a new version of the WL studio, the entire team has to update. Otherwise the platformVersion in the application-descriptor won't match and direct update won't work. We are now even considering to version our eclipse in Git. I would love to get some best practices on this topic?

Comment: I created a new question to discuss this matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643072/best-practices-to-maintain-different-worklight-studio-patch-versions

Answer (score 0):

You can find the different versions of worklight plugins [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/) . You can Directly download from there. Its an IBM authorised. Even when you try to download from market place it will point to this URL.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it got down voted. It a common URL from where even Market place picks from. I really don't understand. If my guess is correct even the links provided above also should be from the same path.