# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - Where to find the 5.0.6 repository?

Tags: eclipse, macos, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying install Worklight 5.0.6 with the IBM update site in Eclipse using "Install new software", but cannot choose version, it is always latest - 6.0.0. Project works only at 5.0.6.

How to install this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question for download links of previous releases (5.0.6.2, 6.0.0.2) and current release (6.1.0.0): [IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases)

The IBM repository site will always contain only the latest version.

Perhaps you should also open another question, detailing what is not working in your project when imported to Worklight 6.0, so that we could help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Idan, that link appears to be broken. Is there anywhere we can download v5.0.6.1?

Comment: 5.0.6.1 is no longer available; you can download either 5.0.6.2, 6.0.0.2 or 6.1.0.0. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases - I've also updated the link in the question.

Comment: thank you for that. I hadn't seen your comment because you didn't (@)mention my name. Thanks again.