# IBM Worklight - How to switch back to version 6.0 from 6.1?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

When installing Worklight from the Eclipse Marketplace, v6.1 is being installed.
How can I switch back to v6.0?

Comment: See my updated answer below for the download link for v6.0.

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot the reply.Even after installing using worklighg 6.0 zip file posted below.it is still showing the latest worklight 6.1 version.please suggest. Thanks Kiran

Comment: Try with a fresh copy of Eclipse and a new workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the updates.It is working fine now.

Comment: @user2748864, please mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight 6.0.0.x Developer Edition is not available for download via Eclipse Marketplace. Only the latest version of the Developer Edition is ever available from Eclipse Marketplace.

To obtain previous versions of Worklight:

1. If you are an IBM customer or business partner, you can get it from either Passport Advantage or Partner World respectively.
2. For the free Developer Edition previous versions are only available as zip files. Here's the [6.0 download](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.1.zip). After downloading, use the eclipse archive install option and point to the downloaded zip file.

Comment: hi... can you update the link for 6.0 version. because i think this one is outdated

Comment: First, use this question instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases

Comment: Second, if you require the latest version for a specific version, don't use any of those URLs. Rather, go to IBM Fix Central and download the latest iFix. IBM Fix Central is the only place where past versions are actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

For the free Developer Edition previous versions you can download from here [6.0.0.2](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.2.zip)