# Nodejs adapters in worklight

Tags: node.js, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am trying to change the compile engine of worklight from rhino to nodejs by following the steps mentioned in [this URL](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/a_preview_of_node_js_adapters_in_worklight_6_0_0?lang=en)

It was specifically mentioned that the above method doesn't work for 6.2 version. I am using 6.2v and tried it once but with no luck...., is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to use nods.js-based adapters in Worklight 6.2, as you have already mentioned.  That is still valid.

You can submit a feature request here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Comment: thank you... , since worklight 6.0 supports this feature i followed your answer given in this url [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606803/ibm-worklight-how-to-switch-back-to-version-6-0-from-6-1) but the download is no longer available , i tried with 6.0.2(from same url) but i got server time out exception, so should we drop this idea of integrating nodejs in worklight for now??