# Worklight developer edition installation error in Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 version

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, eclipse-juno, worklight-studio

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.mobile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.1.0.00-20131219-1900.jar.
Read timed out
```

Comment: You should add **much** more info in order to get some help from other users. What have you been trying to do? Under what circumstances does this happen? How far have you got up until now? ...

Comment: From the very limited information here it looks like either the IBM site is running slowly (or is down) or you need to configure a proxy to access it.

Comment: I would honestly not be surprised if something was wrong with our site with regards to public.dhe.  Are you installing this from markeplace or directly from the repo?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a network timeout as installations from the Eclipse Marketplace seem to work fine now.

Since you're trying to install 6.1, I suggest that you'll simply try again with the latest version, available to download from here: [IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases)