# problems while installing worklight develpoer edition

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

this error occured while installing IBM worklight plugin on eclipse juno 4.2.2

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:
    (profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.
    internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
    Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub
    /software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.
    studio.plugin_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356.jar.
Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a network timeout as installations from the Eclipse Marketplace seem to work fine now.

Since you're trying to install 6.1, I suggest that you'll simply try again with the latest version, available to download from here: [IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases)