# Can I install an older version of Worklight studio?

Tags: installation, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

On my project, we are using version 6.1.0.01 of the Developer's Edition of Worklight studio.  The Eclipse Marketplace only offers version 6.2 now, and we need to onboard a new developer.  Is there anyway to install 6.1.0.01?  (i.e., via a direct download link?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases)

- Worklight 6.2 (from the [Worklight homepage](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight) or from the Eclipse Marketplace)
- Worklight 6.1.0.1 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.1.0.1.zip))
- Worklight 6.0.0.2 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.2.zip))
- Worklight 5.0.6.2 ([direct link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.5.0.6.2.zip))