# Where can i find worklight studio version v6.1? The only version i can find now is v6.2 on eclipse marketplace

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

For some reason, i want the worklight studio version 6.1.0.01.20140427-1450,but the newest worklight version on eclipse marketplace is v6.2, so, where can i find it?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for a list of download URLs for the *latest available* build of previous releases: [Can I install an older version of Worklight studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767777/can-i-install-an-older-version-of-worklight-studio)

If you are an IBM customer or business partner, you should contact IBM to get a *specific build* of a version that you may require.