# eclipse worklight studio 6.2: starting with error in worklight console IPAS does not exist

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ibm-mobilefirst

I download the file `**com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.2.0.01-20141027-1531.jar**` independently,and put it into in ../plugins.but some error occured in worklight console as ' **Source 'D:\eclipse\plugins\com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.2.0.01-20141027-1531.jar\IPAS' does not exist**'.But the IPAS does exist,is there anything I need to set up?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not do "manual installation" of the Worklight Studio plug-in like extracting .jar files and placing them in the Eclipse folder.

IBM supports 2 installation paths for Worklight Studio (latest iFix available):

- By searching for "worklight" in the Eclipse Marketplace
- By downloading the Worklight Studio .zip file from [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/).

Access to IBM Fix Central is available to IBM customers and business partners.

Edit: [You can use the links here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases) to download an older version. But a fair warning: The latest will be available only in the above 2 locations. These links may not be always up-to-date.

Comment: thanks for answer,my network is pretty slow and the file cannot be download correctly,may I get a link to studio.zip?

Comment: If you are an IBM customer, you can login and download it yourself.

Comment: I just don't know where to find the studio.zip,it just show me to install from marketplace

Comment: To get the very latest iFix available for your Worklight version, you need to login to IBM Fix Central (it is a website - google for it) with your customer number. From there, you will be able to download the very latest .zip file for your Eclipse.

Comment: if I have not installed any edition of the worklight before,can I use the the packet you describe?......still....I don't find it,please ......help.......

Comment: still I met the same problem after following your instruction in installing the early version

Comment: it shows 'Source 'D:\eclipse\plugins\com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.1.0.02-20141016-1539.jar\IPAS' does not exist' in worklight console....any setting i missed?

Comment: When does it show it? How do you install Worklight? Did you try with a fresh Eclipse and workspace?

Comment: just after eclipse launch.I download the packet(Worklight 6.1.0.2)through your link,help->install new software->add....,with eclipse luna 4.40