# where to find Worklight plugin for enterprise edition ver 6.2.0.1?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Hi We are using WL enterprise edition version 6.2.0.1 with fix pack 1.

Is there a WL plugin for our version?
If yes,Where can I find the WL plugin inside the server directory?

According to my understanding that the plugin is only for developer edition. but I have been informed that there is a plugin for enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are an IBM customer or Business Partner you can always download the latest available iFix for your version of Worklight/MobileFirst Platform from the [IBM Fix Central website](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/).

None-customers/business partners use the latest available version, currently 6.3, available from the Eclipse Marketplace.

There is also the following, but there is no guarantee that the links will always point to the latest available iFix: [IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases)