# IBM Mobilefirst - Custom direct update is not happening in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp, direct-update

I have used adapter, authentication, server everything of MFP. But now I am stuck in **Direct Update**. If  I am pushing `mfpdev app webupdate` direct update default dialog is coming and I can update application.

But issue is coming while I am trying to make a custom dialog for getting the update. **I never got the custom dialog**. The codes I have used is:\

```
wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = ((directUpdateData, directUpdateContext) => {

      WL.SimpleDialog.show('Update Avalible', 'Press update button to download version 2.0', [{
        text: 'update',
        handler: () => {
          directUpdateContext.start();
        }
      }]);

    });
```

I cant find the `wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler` in worklight.d.ts file either. Seeming like in ionic2 we don't have a option for custom direct update dialog. Am I right?

The version I am using is **Mobilefirst V8.0.0 and Ionic2**

Please help me if anyone have any better understanding on this.

Comment: @VivinK so what should I use for MFP 8.0? Or Is it just that we cant customize it either?

Comment: It can be done. Trying it out.

Comment: Let me know if you have any solution @VivinK

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you declare wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler outside class and then try again?

Comment: But mate wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler not there at all in worklight.d.ts
So basically it will not make in differnce if we will call it from outside or inside. And its not at all throwing any error as well and we think that's expected.

Comment: @Avijit yes you are correct. But its there in worklight.js file, which ultimately gets referenced from the application. So I think if you do it like that way, you should be able to call it. Worth giving a shot. Let me know the findings.

Comment: Custom direct update feature works well in MFP 8.0. The original methods are within worklight.js.