# How To setup IBM Mobile First version 7.1 in eclipse - IBM mobile first not available in eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

Need to setup the IBM mobile-first development studio in eclipse but IBM mobile first not available in eclipse marketplace.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please note that IBM MobileFirst 7.1 is currently in a continuous support mode until September 30, 2020 and will not be supported after that.

The MobileFirst Studio Plugin is not available in Eclipse MarketPlace. You need to download MobileFirst 7.1 Eclipse plugin from [IBM Passport Advantage](https://www.ibm.com/software/passportadvantage/index.html) or [IBM Fix Central](https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/) with your IBM credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below link. Download the Previous releases using the below link,

[IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases)

Import the local downloaded copy to eclipse.